# How to programatically change a view's style_options when user clicking the exposed filter apply button?

Tags: views

In a Leaflet Map view, the exposed filter is a list(text) field. On user clicking the Apply button of the exposed filter form, I need to programatically change the value of $handler->display->display_options['style_options']['map'], I mean to change the Leaflet map style (which is defined in the module leaflet_more_maps).

How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

The hook_views_pre_render() works.

```
function my_misc_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if($view->name == 'classrooms_map') {
    $view->style_plugin->options['map'] = ($view->exposed_data['type'] == 'All') ? 'all' : $view->exposed_data['type'];
  }
}
```